# Laravel pass dynamic varibles in loops

Tags: laravel

in my blade file I have below varables like :

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
```

so in blade file I want to show in loop like

```
@for($i=0;$i>5;$i) 

{{text[$i]}}

@endfor
```

So how can I archive that ?

Comment: put the variables values in an array and iterate through the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{${'text'.$i}}}
```

I hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help:

```
text{{ $i }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
@for($i=1;$i<6;$i++) 

    text{{$i}}

@endfor
```